# PHP API call, finding response value

Tags: php

I'm new to php and API calls, I'm trying to find the email address of my local MP using the parliament API (https://members-api.parliament.uk/index.html)

Challenge is, I can't return the email address directly. I can loop through the results of the call, but I want to return the email to a variable directly. The Problem seems to be in the set of results their is a [ value. (https://members-api.parliament.uk/api/Members/4402/Contact)

I can loop through the nodes and return a value but I cant see what the node value is itself to pull out the name

```
$url = 'https://members-api.parliament.uk/api/Members/'.$ID.'/Contact';
```

$get_data = callAPI('GET', $url, false);
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);

```
$email = $response["value"]["email"];

echo $email;
$ic = 0;
foreach ($response["value"] as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $x){
        //echo $item ;
        //echo '<br>';
        echo $item;
        echo $item[$ic];
        echo 'item<br>';
        echo $x.'<br>';
        $ic = $ic +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: basically there is nothing special in the api responses - they are *just* PHP arrays. you may loop the value array and check element where type is "Parliamentary office". here is your email